# Generate a random range of numbers in excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking for an excel formula to generate a random range of numbers between -0.3 and +0.3. These numbers can be at most 2 decimal places.

E.g here is a list of numbers I would expect this formula to return:

-0.24, 0.02, 0.13, -0.14, 0.3, 0.22, -0.29

and so on...

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats quite easy to do:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(-30;30)/100
```

Comment: Thanks Doerig. Tried up voting you but says it's not displayed as my reputation is less than 15